# android studio newrelic proguard not reporting data

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, newrelic

I'm working with android studio. I've exported a signed APK with new relic and proguard implementation.
This is my gradle.build file:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'newrelic'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
}

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-android.txt'
        }
    }
} 

dependencies {
    compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:4.87.0'
}
```

The required premissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

This is called from my application initializer:

```
NewRelic.withApplicationToken(ConfigurationManager.getInstance().getNewRelicToken())
            .start(MainApplication.getAppContext());
```

in my proguard-android.txt (which used to be called progaurd-project.txt):

```
-keep class com.newrelic.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.newrelic.**
-keepattributes Exceptions, Signature, InnerClasses
```

and I have a newrelic.properties in the same level as proguard-android.txt:

```
com.newrelic.application_token=AAb1405bc1f2e2************************
```

An important thing to mention is that when I run the code unobfuscated I see data being reported.
My problem is that when i export and sign the APK it's not reporting any data.

Comment: A debug level build log captured using the `-d` switch would help determine if there are any issues while implementing New Relic.

Comment: How and where do i add it?

Comment: In Android Studio preferences, under Compiler, add `--debug` to the Command Line Options. The build log that shows New Relic instrumentation info will then be found in the Gradle Console.